# multiple class selector in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this css role

```
.sf-menu a.sf-with-ul{padding-left:20px}
```

I want to change this role using jquery

I tried without success the following commands

```
$(function()
{
     $("a.sf-with-ul").css("padding-left", "10px");
     $("a").hasClass(".sf-with-ul").css("padding-left", "10px");
     $("a").filter(".sf-with-ul").css("padding-left","10px")
});
```

What is the problem?

p.s

I do I change the roll of this css using jquery?

```
.sf-menu li ul li a
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this :**

```
$(function()
{
 $(".sf-menu a.sf-with-ul").css("padding-left", "10px");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put !important like this:

```
$(function()
{
     $("a.sf-with-ul").css("padding-left", "10px !important");
     $("a").hasClass(".sf-with-ul").css("padding-left", "10px !important");
     $("a").filter(".sf-with-ul").css("padding-left","10px !important")
});
```

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary; inline css (as set by `.css()`) will take precedence over that defined in the stylesheet in any case.